# How to Resolve "java.util.Collections$SingletonList cannot be cast to java.util.ArrayList" Issue in Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin, arraylist

I encountered an issue while trying to convert a list using the distinct() method in Kotlin. Here's a simplified version of my code:

```
        val orgList = arrayListOf<ListArticle>()
        orgList.add(list)
        val sortedList = orgList.distinct() as ArrayList<ListArticle>
```

Comment: Why would you even _want_ to make `sortedList` an ArrayList? If a function requires a parameter to be an ArrayList, I would suspect that that function needs refactoring as it probably should accept a `List`. Two principles: (1) [program to an interface, not an implementation](https://www.google.com/search?q=program+to+an+interface%2C+not+an+implementation); and (2) [prefer immutable data](https://www.google.com/search?q=prefer+immutable+data).

Answer (score 0):

Absolutely! We can resolve this issue by simply wrapping the distinct list in an ArrayList() constructor. Here's how:

```
 val list: ArrayList<ListArticle> = ArrayList(orgList.distinct())
```

This converts the distinct list into an ArrayList, ensuring compatibility and avoiding any ClassCastException issues. Smooth sailing ahead!